# Node js reading from excel Arabic and English switch issue

Tags: node.js, excel, xlsx, arabic

This is not a node js issue per se but I am encountering an issue I want to share. I discovered this issue when I was reading the field using https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx. The english was going to the right. I tried copy pasting the field to notepad or word as shown in the image below and it was the same. How can I tackle this. I want to keep the order.

[image]

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want the display to be correct when in "excel"?

Comment: No, I want to read from excel into database, like Firebase. When I read by code, it is switching. So I tried copy pasting that's when I figure out the issue